# Is there always a "k-sparse" subsequence of a multilimit convergent sequence?

Tags: real-analysis

Sorry for the bad lingo. Couldn't find the right terminology.

What I mean by multilimit is:

Let $\{a_n\} \subset \mathbb{R}$, and define:
$$
L = \{p \in \mathbb{R} \quad | \quad \exists \{b_n\} \subset \{a_n\}  \quad b_n \longrightarrow p\}
$$
then L is the multilimit of $a_n$ and this I note as $a_n \longrightarrow L$

What I mean by "k-sparse" subsequence is the following:

Let $a_n$ be a real valued sequence and consider $\{b_n\} \subset \{a_n\}$ such that every term in $b_n$ is every $k$-th term in $a_n$  with $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

My question is:

If $a_n \longrightarrow L \subset \mathbb{R}$, is it true that there must be a $k$-sparse subsequence of $a_n$ such that it converges to some real value in L?

Also if you know what is the correct terminology for this let me know.

Comment: Oh my bad. With "convergent k-sparse subsuccession" I meant convergent towards some single real value rather than then entire L

Comment: is $a_n$ not a sequence of real numbers?

Comment: Nono $a_n$ is in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Can You define $a_n$ more precisely?

Comment: Sure. The $a_n$ sequence is a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ so by that I mean, $a: \mathbb{N} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$. $a_n$ could have any real number as terms. As for the nature of L I just added an edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the properies of $\{a_n\}$.

If $\{a_n\}$ converges to some limit $a$, then so would all subsequences of $\{a_n\}$, and thus the set $L=\{\hspace{1mm}p\hspace{1mm}|\hspace{1mm} \exists\{b_n\}\subset\{a_n\},\hspace{1mm} b_n\to p\}$, would be the singelton set $\{a\}$. In other words, all "k-sparse" subsequences would converge to $a\in L$.

However, if $\{a_n\}$ does not converge then there is not much we can say without more restrictions on $\{a_n\}$.

Example 1: let $\{a_n\}=(-1)^n$. Then $L=\{1,-1\}$, and the "2-sparse" subsequence $(-1)^{2n}$ converges to $1\in L$.

Example 2: let $\{a_n\}=sin(n)$. Then $L$ might be empty or non-empty. In either case, all "k-sparse" subsequences $\{sin(kn)\}$ diverges so they can not be in $L$.

So we cant really say much if $\{a_n\}$ does not converge. There might exists such a "k-sparse" subsequence or there might not.

Also, the notation $a_n \rightarrow L$ is a bit confusing, I would advice to use something else.